# Rss feed changes url to items

Tags: rss

I am implementing a rss feed reader like system and I am having issues with some feeds that change the urls of the items after a while.
When I built the system I used the md5 of the url as an ID to have an easy and fast way to detect duplicates,people will not change the url to the articles because it is bad for SEO but if they use feedproxy or other dynamic feed generator the urls to the articles use redirection and the urls also change,as an example I get this 3 entries into my database for same article

> http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/itsallaboutrevenue/~3/AElJBdzy2nY/your-story-is-not-about-you-content-pros-podcast-episode-2-with-ann-handley

http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/itsallaboutrevenue/~3/YIa4EeZgkJs/your-story-is-not-about-you-content-pros-podcast-episode-2-with-ann-handley

https://blogs.oracle.com/marketingcloud/your-story-is-not-about-you-content-pros-podcast-episode-2-with-ann-handley

My question is what is the correct way to do this ,and if you know some open source code that can be used on server side that is stable,maintained that I can replace my php code that I use now(it can be in any language ) (I am using picofeed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you not use item's id as an unique identifier?

```
// Item object
$feed->items[0]->getId();                      // Item unique id (hash)
```

Picofeed probably creates the hash of the unique id from [RSS item's guid](http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_tag_guid.asp) or if guid is missing they use the link url like you do. Usually feed creators add guids and those should remain unchanged even after the link changes. [Here is some more info about how rss readers detect duplicates.](http://goo.gl/TlSxDD)

Comment: link is broken at this moment

Comment: url fixed, the article can also be found by searching 'RSS Duplicate Detection' on Google

Comment: thnks, I will see if I find a way to migrate the database data to use the new IDs without getting lots of duplicates, I want to keep older articles that are no longer on the feed so I can't delete and start fresh